# CSS animation (transform: rotateY(180deg);) works perfectly except in Chrome on iOS

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome, animation

Long time user, first time poster.

The animations work perfectly on PC and on iPhone firefox/Safari but not on iPhone Chrome. (upto date).

The animations just appear to snap to the end location after the animation duration. I did get it working briefly however I think it was due to it caching an older version of my CSS. and I'm not sure which one or what was different. Point being i know it can work.

Any help greatly appreciated. I cleaned up the code as best I can. The working code has comments EVERYWHERE. There is a little more to the code but this is the core of it.

also running Bootstrap4 for info.

```js
$(".flip-card-inner").on('click mouseenter', function () {
    // $(this).css("animation-play-state", "initial"); // pause Y axis rotate
    // $(this).css("animation-play-state", "paused");

    $("div.link").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(150*index).slideDown("fast");

    $(".flip-card-inner").addClass('fliptoback');


    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height:100vh; 
  background-color: #3a4757;
  background-image: url("img/grey_wash_wall.png");
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;
  background-size: 25%;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: .7rem ;
  border-color: black;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;   
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform; 
    transition: transform;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #181E25;
  background-image: url("img/brushed.jpg");
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size:25%;
  border-radius: .7rem ;
  border-color: #181E25;
  color: white;
 }
  
  /* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #181E25;
    background-image: url("img/brushed.jpg");
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size:25%;
    border-radius: .7rem ;
    border-color: #181E25;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.fliptoback{
  animation-name: yaxis;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes yaxis {
  from   {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
} 
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class=" flip-card-inner" >
    <div class=" flip-card-front" >
      <p>this is the front</p>
    </div>
    <div class=" flip-card-back" >
      <p>this is the back</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="brandbox">
<h3 class="text-center text-light font-weight-light mt-3 text-uppercase">BRAND</h3>

        </div>
    
<div class="link text-light border border-light text-uppercase">
            Website
</div>
```

Comment: I think there is a way to refresh a mobile page with cache disabled, btw

Answer (score 7):

Restarted Chrome. Now works fine. I want to scream.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when using CSS keyframe animations.
It seems that it is a bug in Chrome iOS and has been known for at least 3-4 years.

The problematic behavior that has been reported says that the animations break after you leave the problematic page, open another page, reload that page, and go back to the problematic page, and the issue occurs.
 Another confirmed behavior is that the issue is not present after resetting the Chrome instance and opening the problematic page.
This issue has been pinpointed to be with "UIViews snapshotting" (see links bellow).

Link to the related StackOverflow post:
[Animations lagging on mobile chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385134/animations-lagging-on-mobile-chrome)

The post also has links to the Chromium bug reports:
[Issue 1231712: CSS transitions lag / jank after switching tabs on mobile device chrome browser](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1231712)

[Issue 899130: CSS Transitions Stop Working](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=899130)

The first Chromium link contains another bug report link:
[Bug 228333 - [iOS] CSS transform transitions become janky after snapshotting other UIViews](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=228333),
which states that this bug has reportedly been fixed as of the beginning of January 2023
Fix highlighted here: [[iOS] CSS transform transitions become janky after snapshotting other UIViews #8394](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/8394)

I still have the issue after updating Chrome on iOS on the 28th of January, 2023. I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Feels good to know I’m not crazy.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1249723, This thread is saying this is finally fixed in iOS 16.4 beta 1, but honestly its been 3 years so who knows.

Comment: Updated to iOS 16.4.1. The issue seems to be fixed. Thanks Awnold.